# Calling a Jquery function after the pages is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have got a link with the click event in my JQuery, something like below:

```
$('#TopLoginLink').click(function()
{
//Here I want the current page should be reloaded with "https" and after the page is loaded then it will automatically call my function MyDialogPopup(). Something like below:
var myCurrentPage = window.location.href.replace('#','');
                var reloadURL;

                if (https!=' ')
                {
                    reloadURL = myCurrentPage.replace('#','').replace("http",https);
                    window.location.href = reloadURL;
                    MyDialogPopup();

                }  

});
```

The above code is reloading my page perfectly, however my problem is that my function is also called immediatley, but I want my function should be called only when my page is loaded with "https" completely.

Please suggest! how can I achieve this

Comment: Define "completely" - does that  include images and style sheets? If yes, use `load()`; if no, use `.ready()`:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: what ever, when my login link is clicked on top, its reload the same page with "https"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define some flag. For example put something in cookies or append to url. Then, in your javascript define `ready` handler then will be called when page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     if (checkFlag()){
         MyDialogPopup();
         clearFlag();
     }
});
```

Your handler will be looking like this:

```
if (https!=' ')
{
    reloadURL = myCurrentPage.replace('#','').replace("http",https);
    setFlag();
    window.location.href = reloadURL;
}
```

If your stick with cookies, you can use [jquery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin. Here is code for `setFlag`, `checkFlag`, `clearFlag`:

```
function setFlag(){
    $.cookie('show_dlg', 'true');
}

function clearFlag(){
    $.cookie('show_dlg', null);
}
function checkFlag(){
    return $.cookie('show_dlg') == 'true';
}
```

Comment: @Thanks GOR, my confusion is that where I should write the above code, I mean I have got on javascript file, which have one $(document).ready and inside that I am having my login click event,, where I am reloading same page with HTTPS, please suggest

Comment: you can use as many `ready` handlers as you wish. Just add my code to your file, and change your handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // all your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `MyDialogPopup` method call in `$(document).ready` and not after modifying the `window.location.href`:

```
$(function() {
    if (do some checks on the url if we need to call the method) {
        MyDialogPopup();
    }
});
```

Comment: @MKS, not the click event, the call to the `MyDialogPopup`. It's OK that you have the click even in document ready and that's how it should be but once you redirect using `window.location.href` this same document ready will be triggered once the page is loaded and it will execute the `MyDialogPopup()` function. Just make sure that you perform the same test on the url or this function will always be triggered even the first time the page loads which is not what you want I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @Darin Can you please give some example code, I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code executes once the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```